# чтение гугл таблицы с кирилицей в названии

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-spreadsheet

использую библиотеку googleapis,
необходимо получить данные из гугл таблицы, в таблице могут быть листы и при попытке сделать запрос с `range:'[кириллица]!A1:N'` выходит ошибка: `TypeError [ERR_UNESCAPED_CHARACTERS]: Request path contains unescaped characters`
как нужно составлять запрос к таким листам?
пробовал подставлять id листа и юникод, не помогло

так же буду благодарен, если укажите, как получить список всех листов внутри таблицы

Answer (score 0):

Мне помог такой приём:

`range: encodeURIComponent('Название таблицы на русском!A1:B2')`